# Filters in JerseyTest 2.x

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm writing a test using JerseyTest v2.5 and the Grizzly container. My Resource depends on a filter that's defined in my web.xml, so the test is failing.

Is there a way to configure a servlet filter when using JerseyTest?

Even better, is there a way to use my web.xml to configure the servlet container?

Comment: What type of filter are you using? Could you please post your resource code and web.xml?

Answer (score 9):

There an issue about that already opened that you might have seen : https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2259

Ultimately, it seems like

> you can't currently register servlet and filter class 
>   concurrently with jersey test framework (setting one will erase the other).

*This quote is taken from [this reply by Pavel Bucek](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Filter-not-executing-when-running-a-JerseyTest-tp4971178p4975210.html).*

I wonder if you saw it, he seems to have found a workaround, but I'm not sure if that would be applicable for you.

> What you can do is deploy your application on (for example) embedded 
>   glassfish and run your tests against it using support for external 
>   container. Command for executing tests will look like:
>
> jersey version 1.2+:
>
> mvn test
>
> - Djersey.test.containerFactory=com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.external.ExternalTestContainerFactory
> - Djersey.test.port=XXX -Djersey.test.host=XXX
>
> jersey version 1.1.5.1-:
>
> mvn test
>
> - Djersey.test.containerFactory=com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.external.ExternalTestContainerFactory
> - DJERSEY_HTTP_PORT=XXX -DJERSEY_HOST_NAME=XXX

Answer (score 2):

I did not test it but maybe this helps you.

Having a filter

```
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest webRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        final HttpSession session = webRequest.getSession();
        ......

    }
}
```

You can define your resource configuration class and then register your filter

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyResourceConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    // Initializes all resources from your REST package.

    public MyResourceConfig() {
        // add your package name to enable package scanning for resources.
        packages("com.myapp.rest");
        // or you can register your resource class directly
        register(YourResource.class);
        register(MyFilter.class);
    }
}
```

then, in your Jersey Test class

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new MyResourceConfig ();
}
```

or in a more easy way

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(YourResource.class).register(MyFilter.class);
}
```

if you need setting a property to your filter you can do

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new MyResourceConfig ().property("property", "value");
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(YourResource.class).register(MyFilter.class).property("property", "value");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After researching this further, it seems that it is not possible to combine servlet filters with JerseyTest - whatever that should be applied must be implemented as Jersey/JAX-RS filters.

To test in combination with servlet filters, the WAR must be deployed in a servlet container (embedded or otherwise).